# How to interrupt a running command in linux and continue from the last state later?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I run a sh script on terminal of linux remote server using ssh which will take very long. I need to power off my machine and I want to save the current state of execution and continue later from the last state. I'm using `source main.sh` command and currently be executed.
I looked at the similar questions but they are related to specific languages.

Comment: If you mean to power off the remote server, then this is not possible in a general way. It may be possible if the script or the called program is somehow prepared for this, e.g. by writing state information and/or partial results to a file. If you want to power off the local machine, see the answer about `screen`. In this case the program will continue to run while you are disconnected, so saving its state is not necessary.

Comment: `screen/tmux/tail -f log`

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `screen` command which lets you keep running a shell session on a server even when you're disconnected. You can later connect to the same session and see its progress.

Comment: You beat me to it, this is a case for screen, unless the person needs to be viewing the progress, at which point it's basically not possible.

Comment: @Lizardx `screen` has a scrollback buffer

Comment: @roaima, and can log the output of screen windows, see `info screen log`.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear,  meant needed to watch in real-time. I recall that the scrollback was not big enough, but I can't say I use screen much, but that was the issue I had with it for certain purposes. I believe it can be adjusted but I recall the upper limit being too low for my needs.

Comment: @Lizardx, the size of the scrollback buffer is customizable.